# How to filter multiple file-extensions to limit which files display in an operator's file-selector?

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, file-browser

I'm creating an image file importer based off the operator_file_import template. I want to set script so that it recognizes image files, because right now it's only recognizing text. How do I go about defining a list of extensions that show up in the file browser when I launch the script? Right now, based on the starting template, the only thing I can import is a .txt file.

Here is the code - The generic comments are still there and anything that I changed is indicated by a comment/CHANGED tag.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
import collections
import os
from bpy.props import (
        StringProperty,
        BoolProperty,
        EnumProperty,
        IntProperty,
        FloatProperty,
        CollectionProperty,
        )
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ImportHelper
from bpy.types import Operator


#CHANGED read definition to class name
def read_pbr_textures(context, filepath, use_some_setting):   
    print("running read_pbr_textures..")
    f = open(filepath, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    data = f.read()
    f.close()

    # would normally load the data here
    print(data)

    return {'FINISHED'}


#CHANGED class name
class ImportPbrTextures(Operator, ImportHelper):   
    """This appears in the tooltip of the operator and in the generated docs"""
    bl_idname = "import_test.pbr_textures"  # important since its how bpy.ops.import_test.some_data is constructed
    bl_label = "Import PBR Textures"

#CHANGED filename_ext to png
    # ImportHelper mixin class uses this
    filename_ext = "*.png"

    filter_glob = StringProperty(
            default="*.png",
            options={'HIDDEN'},
            maxlen=255,  # Max internal buffer length, longer would be clamped.
            )

    # List of operator properties, the attributes will be assigned
    # to the class instance from the operator settings before calling.
    use_setting = BoolProperty(
            name="Example Boolean",
            description="Example Tooltip",
            default=True,
            )

    type = EnumProperty(
            name="Example Enum",
            description="Choose between two items",
            items=(('OPT_A', "First Option", "Description one"),
                   ('OPT_B', "Second Option", "Description two")),
            default='OPT_A',
            )

    def execute(self, context):
        return read_some_data(context, self.filepath, self.use_setting)


# Only needed if you want to add into a dynamic menu
def menu_func_import(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(ImportPbrTextures.bl_idname, text="Text Import Operator")

#CHANGED class registration to ImportPbrTextures class
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ImportPbrTextures)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_import.append(menu_func_import)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ImportPbrTextures)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_import.remove(menu_func_import)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.import_test.pbr_textures('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Comment: This question isn't spesific to image importing, its just about extensions.

Comment: The script doesn't run `AttributeError: Calling operator "bpy.ops.import_test.some_data" error, could not be found
`

Comment: The code works, ie only shows png files,  however you are test calling `import_test.some_data` rather than `import_test.pbr_textures` ... perhaps the former still had ".txt" as a glob.

Comment: script now works and points to .png files. Problem was as batFINGER said, `bpy.ops.import_test.some_data` needed to be changed to `import_test.pbr_textures`

Comment: All this code does is point to the image files now. Upon trying to load and read the images, I am met with this error: `line 64, in execute
NameError: name 'read_some_data' is not defined`

How do I define the script to read these files? Or more specifically, how can I make this script load the image into a texture node?

Comment: You have changed the method name to `read_pbr_textures`

Comment: Your question has been edited and now asks about `UnicodeDecodeError`. Reverted those edits. Please as a **different question** for further queries. If you run into multiple issues developing your script, just ask multiple separate questions, instead of editing once the first is solved.

Answer (score 3):

In the operator's `filter_glob` property, (which you've already defined), you can define multiple extensions using the `;` separator, eg:

```
filter_glob = StringProperty(
        default="*.png;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.bmp;*.exr",
        options={'HIDDEN'},
        )
```

If you want to make a list of all extensions Blender supports you can use. `bpy.path.extensions_image` eg:

```
"*" + ";*".join(bpy.path.extensions_image)
```

Comment: works properly! File importer script now points to multiple extensions

Comment: @lvxejay  bpy.path.extesions_image is a set of all image formats supported (by extension)

Comment: @ideasman42 Where are these operator's properties documented. I cannot to seem to find any description of them besides in Blender source.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from http://web.purplefrog.com/~thoth/blender/python-cookbook/image-to-material-node.html :

```
def image_for(fname):
    candidates = [ img for img in bpy.data.images if img.filepath == fname]
    if len(candidates)<1:
        return bpy.data.images.load(fname)
    else:
        return candidates[0]

def node_of_type(nodes, type):
    for node in nodes:
        if node.type == type:
            return node

def mission1(fname):

    mat = bpy.data.materials.get("material")
    if mat is None:
        mat = bpy.data.materials.new("material")

    mat.use_nodes = True
    nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes

    n1 = node_of_type(nodes, "TEX_IMAGE")
    if n1 is None:
        n1 = nodes.new("ShaderNodeTexImage")

    n1.location = (-200,0)
    n1.image = image_for(fname)

    bsdf = node_of_type(nodes, 'BSDF_DIFFUSE')

    mat.node_tree.links.new(bsdf.inputs[0], n1.outputs[0])

    coord = node_of_type(nodes, 'TEX_COORD')
    if coord is None:
        coord = nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexCoord')
    coord.location = (-400,0)

    mat.node_tree.links.new(n1.inputs['Vector'], coord.outputs['UV'])

    return mat

mat = mission1("/home/thoth/art/dancing-bear/bear384.png")
bpy.context.active_object.data.materials[0] = mat
```